# How to validate query string in Logic App

Tags: validation, http, query-string, azure-logic-apps

How do I validate query string in Logic App
I have the following url with query string param

```
http://myapi?from=a&to=b
```

I want to report an error if any of the query strings are incorrect. The below would generate an error along the line of 'tooo' is not a valid param.

```
http://myapi?from=a&tooo=b
```

I really dont want to have lots of 'if-statements' as it would make the graphic design very large.
Can this be done in Javascript inline code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following inline Javascript code.

```
var allowedQueryParam = ["from", "to"];

var qs =workflowContext.trigger.outputs.queries ;
var reqQueryStrings = Object.keys(qs);


for (i = 0; i < reqQueryStrings.length; i++) {
       if(allowedQueryParam.includes(reqQueryStrings[i]) == false){
         return reqQueryStrings[i]+ " is not valid";
     }
}
```